# How to read a json file from resource directory in Android Studio?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, arraylist

I have a `json` file that contains country names and their respective country code. I'm trying to build a country code picker but first I need to read the `json` file into a `JSONArray` from the `resource` directory, how do I do that? I currently have the `json` file in the `raw` folder inside the `resource` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

**raw/**

> Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources
> with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the
> resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.
>
> However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy,
> you might consider saving some resources in the assets/ directory
> (instead of res/raw/). Files in assets/ aren't given a resource ID, so
> you can read them only using AssetManager.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources